# Android google map display

Tags: android, google-maps

I am displaying the google map in the emaluator..

Here is code snippet ..

In the given code snippet I have added an editbox using xml, and in this editbox a user to enters the name of the location which he wants to search ..

The problem is that I am not able to get the name entered by the user and search that respective location.

```
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());    
    try {

        go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                 result = edit.getText().toString();              
            }

    });

        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(result, 5);
        String add = "";
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            p = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                    (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));
            mc.animateTo(p);
            mc.setZoom(17);
            mapView.invalidate();
        }    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i have used geocoder ..

here is the xml code snippet..

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/edit"
android:layout_width="257px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="18sp"
>
</EditText>
<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="44px"
android:layout_height="33px"
android:text="GO"
>
</Button>
```

Can u pls find me the error and correct me?

Comment: Is an exception being thrown when you run this code?  My initial guess is that your `edit` object (which I assume is an EditText) is invalid.  You may just want to call `findViewById(r.id.editTextID)` in the `onClick`.

Comment: r u getting value for result in ur 5th line? or there u face the pbm? Please explain...

Answer (score 0):

Sine you are saying that you aren't able to get the name entered by the user I am going to provide this as a method for getting the text entered by the user

```
private string getUserSearch(){
   EditText query = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
   return query.getText();
}
```

Then do this

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    result = getUserSearch();              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the following block of code

```
List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(result, 5);
        String add = "";
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            p = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                    (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));
            mc.animateTo(p);
            mc.setZoom(17);
            mapView.invalidate();
        }    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

supposed to be inside the `onClick` method ? Currently all you do in the onClick is update the value of `result` argument. The searching of addresses and showing on map part isn't being called after that